# images rotation javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, rotation

Can not get my query to work. Please advise what I'm missing:

HTML:

```
<div class="images-rotation"
     data-images='["U:\emalcolm\BTHOW\web design\sladex-images-rotation-4430259\imagestub.jpg",
    "U:\emalcolm\BTHOW\web design\sladex-images-rotation-4430259\imageseverafter.jpg",
    "U:\emalcolm\BTHOW\web design\sladex-images-rotation-4430259\imagesoneday.jpg",
    "U:\emalcolm\BTHOW\web design\sladex-images-rotation-4430259\infinity.jpg"]'>
  <img src="U:\emalcolm\BTHOW\web design\sladex-images-rotation-4430259\2013.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$.fn.imagesRotation = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
            images:["U:\emalcolm\BTHOW\web design\sladex-images-rotation-4430259\imagestub.jpg",
 "U:\emalcolm\BTHOW\web design\sladex-images-rotation-4430259\imageseverafter.jpg",
 "U:\emalcolm\BTHOW\web design\sladex-images-rotation-4430259\imagesoneday.jpg",
 "U:\emalcolm\BTHOW\web design\sladex-images-rotation-4430259\infinity.jpg"] ,// urls to images
            dataAttr: 'images', // html5 data- attribute which contains an array with urls to images
            imgSelector: 'img', // element to change
            interval: 1000,     // ms
            intervalFirst: 500, // first image change, ms
            callback: null      // first argument would be the current image url

    },
```

Comment: Ooops, it looks like you are using https://github.com/sladex/images-rotation and try to overwrite the extension with a custom implementation. If you just want to use the plugin as it is you'll have to call `$('.images-rotation').imagesRotation();`
Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), please?

Comment: `doesn't work` is not a question...what is or isn't it doing? What errors are thrown? Why do your image paths have a drive letter in them and why aren't they web path formatted url?

Comment: I dont receive an error on my page.  The functionality of the javascript is not working.  Only the img src shows on the page, the animation is not working for the other four images i have placed inside data-images='[]'

Comment: @RainerRillke    http://jsfiddle.net/c93g2ppm/

Comment: @charlietfl   I dont receive an error on my page. The functionality of the javascript is not working. Only the img src shows on the page, the animation is not working for the other four images i have placed inside data-images='[]

Comment: you are not using url paths to files. You don't load script tags from directory paths with a drive in them like `src="U:\emalcolm\B` . Use url paths either relative ones or absolute ( with protocol & host ). Also learn how to use browser console to check for errors

Comment: There are several problems with the fiddle.

Comment: Improved fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0898py8e/1/: `data-images` attribute should be probably valid JSON. HEAD sections are not required, instead list imports in the sidebar under External Resources, img sources should be [URLs](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img#HTML_Attributes), so you want [`file:///U:/emalcolm/...`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) or similar.